# Rig and Armature don't move together

Tags: modeling, rigging, armature

[image]

I can't seem to get the model, rig and bones to all move together when I generate the rig with rigify.

Does anyone know what I did or maybe where I can find a solution?

Comment: Your rig is ok. You move IK hand, but FK one stays untouched. This rig allows you to use either IK of FK on demand (there is a switch in the tig props), and just disable extra bones (that you don't use right now. e.g. FK hands) display in the rig's UI. Also hide the source metarig to an unused invisible collection for later use =)